# Distribute Spans Evenly With Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, web-applications, twitter-bootstrap

I am working with a fluid-responsive bootstrap project. I have four spans; my goal is to show them 4x1, then 2x2, followed by 1x4. I am having trouble doing this without transitioning through 3x1+1.

To show that graphically:

[image: Responsive design target]

The only code I've found that works is below; in the 4x1 layout, it leaves a wide space between items 2 and 3.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="span11">
        <div class="span5">
            <h2>Item 1</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="span5">
            <h2>Item 2</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="span11">
        <div class="span5">
            <h2>Item 3</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="span5">
            <h2>Item 4</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default bootstrap grid is 12 columns. Did you customize? If so, share that code. Even if you did customize and are using an 11 column grid (which seems like a bad idea by the way) you are only using spans adding up to 10 inside of an 11 column container.

In the fluid grid for bootstrap here is the proper way to nest spans:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span12">
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span6"></div>
                <div class="span6"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The key here being that when you nest, you need to open up a new row-fluid div. In your case, if you only care about the two boxes then you can just do those .spans from the first row-fluid div and not even specify the span class for the full amount. Also, remember to make your inner span classes on each row add up to the total number of columns

Comment: I am using a 'stock' copy of the current version of bootstrap, compiled from less. I understand what you're saying, but it doesn't seem to be working for me. Take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/X6CKZ/

Comment: In the fluid grid You need to make each row-fluid add up to the total amount of columns of your grid. Inside of your span6, you have 2 span3's where you should have 2 span6's. The bootstrap responsive is also preventing it from working in the fiddle because it picks up a screen size so small that it makes each .span* class 100% wide

Comment: When I look at that fiddle, I see four fluid spans, but nothing responsive. If I comment in the responsive css, everything breaks. Accepted your question either way, thanks for taking the time to help me!

Comment: The responsive doesn't really break it, it shows it the way bootstrap wants to show the grid at a very small browser size. Because it is grabbing the size of the small view box in jsfiddle you are seeing each span div on a separate row. This is ideal for mobile layouts, and is actually very helpful and preferable. If you don't want this layout to render than you can customize the css at that particular media query or not include responsive at all

Answer (score 0):

I would just create a custom grid size for this. If you are familiar with LESS you can edit the grid.less files or add something like:

```
.col-quarter {
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
}
.col-half {
 width: 50%;
 float:left;
}
.col-third {
 width: 33%;
 float:left;
}
```

This doesn't account for any padding and margins but its a starting place.

Comment: You could probably scratch this answer and use some grid nesting: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-nesting